# Memory Leak with Copying a Character Pointer

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

Since `strsep` is a destructive operation, I want to preserve the contents of the `line` array, so I make a copy of `line` and assign it to the variable `newline`. I then do the destructive operation on `newline`. I then try to free `newline` but I am getting a memory leak. I'm not 100% sure, but the memory leak is likely due to `newline` not being entirely freed. Before, when I performed the `strsep` operation destructively on `line`, I did not get the memory leak. I am compiling my C code with `fsanitize=address` to uncover the memory leak.

```
struct Item {
    char* line;
    struct Item *next;
};

struct Item* getArguments(char *line) {
  struct Item *current = NULL;
  struct Item *next = NULL;
  struct Item *first = NULL;
  char *found = NULL;
  char *newline = strdup(line);
  char blank[] = "";
  while ((found = strsep(&newline," \n")) != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(found, blank) != 0) {
        next = malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
        next->next = NULL;
        next->line = malloc((strlen(found)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(next->line, found);
        if (current) {
          current->next = next;
        }
        current = next;
        if (first == NULL) {
          first = current;
        }
      }
  }
  free(found);
  free(newline);
  newline = NULL;
  return first;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: `found = strsep(&newline, ...` will modify both `found` and `newline` so when you do `free(found);
  free(newline);` the values are wrong.... and freeing both is wrong

Comment: In other words... you need to save the original value of `newline` and use that for a single call of `free`, i.e. `char *newline = strdup(line); char* saved = newline; .... // code .... free(saved);`

Comment: Thanks @SupportUkraine, that seemed to get rid of the memory leak

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed argument to `const char *line` as you explicitly don't modify it.
2. Retain a copy of address returned by `strdup(line)` for use with `free()` as `strsep()` modifies that pointer.  Made it a const pointer to be really explicit about it.
3. Don't `free(found)`.
4. Minimized scope of variables.
5. Assignments in a condition is a little hard to read so I changed the loop early return loop construct.
6. `if(!*found)` is the same as `char blank[] = "": strcmp(found, blank)` to check for empty string.
7. Check the return value of `malloc()` and `strdup()` and handle clean-up on failure. This change adds a lot of noisy error handling.
8. `if(current)` and `if(first == NULL` is really just a special case around the first iteration so collapsed those into `if`-`else`.
9. (not fixed) You could replace the `malloc()` with a `calloc()` to eliminate the line `next->next = NULL`.
10. (not fixed) Consider tweaking the interface to allow caller to differentiate between memory allocation errors and no strings found.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Item {
    char *line;
    struct Item *next;
};

void freeArguments(struct Item *first) {
    while (first) {
        struct Item *tmp = first->next;
        free(first->line);
        free(first);
        first = tmp;
    }
}

struct Item *getArguments(const char *line) {
    struct Item *first = NULL;
    char *const newline = strdup(line);
    if(!newline)
        goto err;
    char *newline2 = newline;
    for (struct Item *current = NULL;;) {
        char *found = strsep(&newline2," \n");
        if(!found)
            break;
        if (!*found)
            continue;
        struct Item *next = malloc(sizeof *next);
        if(!next)
            goto err;
        next->line = strdup(found);
        if(!next->line)
            goto err;
        next->next = NULL;
        if (first)
            current->next = next;
        else
            first = next;
        current = next;
    }
    free(newline);
    return first;
err:
    freeArguments(first);
    free(newline);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    const char *s = "hello\nworld again";
    struct Item *first = getArguments(s);
    for (struct Item *current = first; current; current = current->next)
        printf("%s\n", current->line);
    freeArguments(first);
}
```

and valgrind seems happy:

```
==1734409== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1734409==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1734409==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,108 bytes allocated
==1734409== 
==1734409== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```